# OGR SQL Query not working in VRT layer

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr, vrt, geospatial-pdf

I'm having trouble with one SQL query I'm using on a shapefile in my VRT layer. My goal is to import several shapefiles to a PDF using OGR, GDAL and Python.

My shapefile has follwing structure: `shapefile1.shp: {FID: integer, Type: string, Name: string, Show: integer ...}`. Nothing out of the usual, no spaces, no underscores, no points.

If I call `ogrinfo` on a OSGeo Shell, the shapefile behaves nominally and all attributes are shown, i.e:

```
> ogrinfo -sql "SELECT Type AS foo FROM shapefile1" shapefile1.shp

 Layer name: shapefile1
 Geometry: Point
 Feature Count: 19
 [...]
 foo: String (150.0)
 OGRFeature(shapefile1):1
 foo (String) = correctString
 POINT (coordinates)
 [...]
```

But if I use the same SQL query on my VRT file, I get following error:

```
ERROR 1: Unrecognized field name Type.
ERROR 1: SQL statement failed, or returned no layer result:
SELECT Type AS foo FROM shapefile1
ERROR 1: Invalid geometry field index : 0
```

This is my VRT file:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="points">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">shapefile1.shp</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL>SELECT Type AS foo FROM shapefile1</SrcSQL>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

First I thought that OGR doens't like attribute names as "FID", "Type", "Name" and so on. But even if i change the SQL query to `SELECT Show AS foo FROM shapefile1` the error keeps appearing. Even on an attribute called `Azimuth`, which should definetly not be a problem.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the field name in quotes?

Comment: I have, but `SELECT "Type" AS foo FROM shapefile1` throws the same error. I even tried with up to 4 quote marks on each side.

Comment: Related? [Merging layers via Python OGR ExecuteSQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239346/84455) by user30184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with your .vrt file and a shapefile that I digitized for the test.

```
ogrinfo vrt.vrt -al
INFO: Open of `vrt.vrt'
      using driver `OGR_VRT' successful.

Layer name: points
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 2
Extent: (705.000000, 467.000000) - (837.000000, 491.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
foo: String (1.0)
OGRFeature(points):0
  foo (String) = a
  POINT (837 491)

OGRFeature(points):1
  foo (String) = b
  POINT (705 467)
```

My GDAL version is 2.3.0-dev.

Comment: Thanks for your time and test. I just digitized a similar shapefile and it works too on GDAL 2.2.4. I´m starting to believe that there is something wrong with the shapefile, but I don't quite understand why `ogrinfo` gets it correct and the SQL query throws an error...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your time, answers and comments. I finally found out what was missing.

The SQL query and everything was fine, the shapefile was just missing its `.dbf` part. Turns out that OGR is capable to read the attributes with the `.shp` and `.shx` parts, but for GDAL the `.dbf` part seems to be mandatory.

Comment: Mysterious. Only place where the attributes os shapefile exist is .dbf file. OGR is part of GDAL so that makes no difference. If you see the attributes the .dbf file must be found somewhere.